# Netty's DnsNameResolverBuilder behaves differently on different platforms

Tags: java, scala, netty

I have some code using Netty's DnsNameResolverBuilder, which works perfectly well on one Linux machine, but, when run on another one, fails to initialize, throwing the null pointer exception below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.<init>(DnsNameResolver.java:217)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.build(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:348)
```

This is caused by the `DnsNameResolverBuilder.build()` call, without actually doing any name resolution.  The small test example has no dependencies other than netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar.  I using scala, and compiling on each machine separately.

Works well on:

```
 $ scala -version
 Scala code runner version 2.12.0-M1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

 $ java -version
 java version "1.8.0_92"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Fails on:

```
# scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.0 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

# java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

The Netty jar is identical (I copied it from one machine to the other), and there are no other jars in the classpath (other than the code to reproduce).

**What could be the cause of this?**  Is this a JVM incompatibility issue? The code is identical, the platforms are near identical, and it's only initializing, not calling out to the network.

And, if there's no obvious answer: How do I go about trying to determine it?